# Understanding PDO class initialization

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a class containing some instance variables:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
}
```

and a mysql table containing th above fields **+ some additional fields** like updated_at. I try to instantiate objects of the above class using pdo and converting them into a json array with the following code:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `mytable`');
$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'MyClass');
$objects =  $statement->fetchAll();

echo json_encode( (array) $objects );
```

It now appears that the resulting array also contains the additional fields although they are not part of my class definition:

```
[{"id": 5, "name":"a name", "updated_at":"<timestamp>", "created_at":"<timestamp>"}]
```

How can this be and whats the best way to avoid this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need this class at all?

Comment: data will be modified before its actually printed out

Comment: Your `SELECT * FROM mytable` isn't doing anything to limit the columns returned... the `*` means get all columns, and just because you have some properties defined in a class doesn't automagically make the database aware of the fact that you only want columns matching those property names. if you want to return just id and name then your SQL statement needs to enforce this.

Comment: yeah but how can PDO set object variables that arent present in my class definition? Im new to PHP and want to understand how this can be.

Comment: PDO can set new object properties because PHP allows new object properties to be created simply by assigning a value to an object property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass
{
    public $id;
    public $name;


    protected function setSelection() {
        return implode(
            ',',
            array_map(
                function ($value) {
                    return '`'.$value.'`';
                },
                array_keys(get_object_vars($this))
            )
        );
    }

    public function getData() {
        ....
        $statement = $pdo->prepare(
            'SELECT ' . $this->setSelection() . ' FROM `mytable`'
        );
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for that! Way better than my approach to write the name of 15 fields into the statement :>

Comment: Of course, it could still cause problems if you had properties that didn't match column names in your table, but it can simplify things for you